# How to get index from array - graphql?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, graphql

I need to know the array item index when it's not returned by downstream response. Suppose my schema looks like

```
schema:
type Cart {
   items: [Item]
}

type Item {
   name: String
   index: Int
}
```

data comes:

```
 {items: [{name: apple}, {name: mango},]}
```

resolvers look like:

```
Cart: {
   items(obj, context, info) {
     return obj;
   }
}

Item: {
   name(obj, context, info) {
     return obj.name;
   }
   index(obj, context, info) {
     // how to get it?
   }
}
```

How to get `ith index` in items array?

Comment: If it’s sequential record previous index then you know what the next one would be..

Comment: I edited the resolver and put comment - is it in info object?

Comment: May be call it id instead of index and auto-increment it, then get it the same way you’re getting the name..

Comment: Can we put something in Cart's resolver and pass id/index from there with item object? It's array and auto-resolved to Item type.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reutrn multiple item for one card in item then

```
  type Cart {
     items: [Item]!
  }
  type Item {
     name: String!
     index: Int!
  }

  Query {
    cardItems: [Cart]!
  }
 resolver {
   cardItems : () => {
    //Perform opration and make result like this to run query properly
    return [{ items: [{ name: 'name1', index: 0 }, ...]}]       
    //Which is array of items contain name and index
   }
  }
  // Query to get result
  {
    cardItems {
      items {
        name
        index
      }
    }
  }
```

But if you wan to specific index of item in a cart you should taken id or index unique key and make anohter query

```
Query {
  itemById(itemId: String!): Item
}
resolver {
    itemById({ itemId }) {
    //perform opration and return item with respeact to itemId
    return { name: 'string', index: 1}
    },
}

//Query to get result
{
  itemById(itemId: "1"){
    name
    index
  }
}
```

resolver reutrn index or itemId based result.